# Is there an issur of Lifnei iver with animals on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, halacha-theory, animals, orach-chaim

In Halacha, Jews are forbidden from having animals do prohibited melachot on Shabbat. My question is, is there any issur of Lifnei iver with animals, or no, since animals don’t have the same free will humans do? As an example, putting an electronic color on a dog, which  the dog could activate on Shabbat, before Shabbat would be setting the animal up to cause melacha on Shabbat, so would it be Lifnei iver?

Comment: Is it your animal or someone else’s?

Comment: An animal is allowed to violate Shabbos. A person cannot have an animal violate Shabbos for them. So, any question about lifnei iveir would be about the person for whom the animal would be working. (For example, Shulchan Arukh OC 246:3, one can lend an animal to a non-Jew on Shabbos knowing the animal would be put to work. But one may not lease out an animal if that means they are making money on even the possibility of the animal doing melakhah on Shabbos.)